# Array adapter in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, arrays, list, listview

Consider:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item);
```

Here in (R.layout.list_item) this part list_item is not working. It shows an error.

How can I fix this error? I am new in the app development sector.

Comment: Your question lacks code and error information. You better check [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question accordingly if you want to get more help.

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 0):

3 parameters

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.custom_list_item, items);







/**
 * Constructor. This constructor will result in the underlying data collection being
 * immutable, so methods such as {@link #clear()} will throw an exception.
 *
 * @param context The current context.
 * @param resource The resource ID for a layout file containing a TextView to use when
 *                 instantiating views.
 * @param objects The objects to represent in the ListView.
 */
public ArrayAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @LayoutRes int resource, @NonNull T[] objects) {
    this(context, resource, 0, Arrays.asList(objects));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are encountering an error with the line `ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item);` where `R.layout.list_item` is not working, it could be due to a few reasons. Here are a couple of possible solutions:

**Verify that list_item.xml exists:**

1. Check if you have a layout XML file named list_item.xml in your
   project's res/layout directory. If it doesn't exist, create a new XML
   file named `list_item.xml`.
2. Make sure the file name and its extension are correct, as incorrect
   naming can cause the error.
3. Ensure that the XML file is properly formatted and doesn't contain
   any errors.

**Clean and rebuild your project:**

1. Sometimes, resource-related issues can be resolved by cleaning and
   rebuilding your project in Android Studio.
2. Go to "Build" in the menu bar and select **"Clean Project"** to clean the
   project. After the cleaning process is complete, go to "Build" again
   and select "Rebuild Project" to rebuild it.
3. This process helps ensure that all resources are correctly compiled
   and accessible.

**Check the import statement:**

1. Confirm that you have the correct import statement for `R.layout.list_item`.
2. The import statement should be `import com.yourpackagename.R;` (replace
   `yourpackagename` with the actual package name of your application).
3. If you see an import statement like `android.R,` remove it, as it can
   cause conflicts with your own resources.

Comment: This answer was likely generated by blindly pasting the question into [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) and blindly pasting the output into the answer box, without ***any*** understanding of the answer or if it actually (correctly) answers the question.